# Tuples AND row_factory functionality via Python classes

Tags: python, class, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 in Python and was wondering if there was a way to choose between a Cursor object and Row object for the same database table using a Python class.

In other words, can I do something like this:

```
class get_db:
  def __init__(self, dbpath):
    con = sqlite3.connect(dbpath, isolation_level=None)
    self.tups = con.cursor()

    con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    self.dict = con.cursor()
```

Then I can return the same value via:

```
db = get_db('/path/to/sql.db')
db.tups.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=24").fetchone()[0]  # For the first tuple element
db.dict.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=24").fetchone()['id'] # Which is the first tuple element as well
```

Right now it seems you must choose one or the other when creating the connection. The above example returns the Row object since row_factory was called last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important thing to consider is that the connection object's execute method is a shorthand.
It creates a cursor, transparently, and returns that cursor's execute method.

When you set the connection object's row_factory attribute to be sqlite3.Row, it is done on the whole connection -- now cursors that are created by this connection will have that set for their row_factory.

What you probably want is to do

```
class get_db:
    def __init__(self, dbpath):
        con = sqlite3.connect(dbpath, isolation_level=None)
        self.tups = con.cursor()

        self.dict = con.cursor()
        self.dict.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
```

so that only the self.dict cursor gets it's row_factory changed.